# Lion disable animation of fullscreen

Tags: osx-lion, fullscreen

On Mac OS 10.7.2, how can I disable or quicken the slow animation that happens when I fullscreen most apps?

Comment: Well i am sorry to say this but as i looked for you there is no way to turn it off

the only thing you can do is that tell Apple to fix your problem

Here are some urls that might help you

   http://www.apple.com/contact/
   http://www.apple.com/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.chromescreen.com/speed-up-mountain-lion/

Look at point number 6.

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this like there is in Windows. There is a program that the guide suggests, called TotalSpaces (http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/). I have no experience at all with it, but the guide suggests it may be able to help you.

I'm sorry I don't have better info for you :(

Comment: TotalSpaces only affects the animations for changing spaces but not the animations for entering or exiting full screen.